# First attempt at creating a React component node_module empty on npm install

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

I have made a basic React component `Persons` that I include in a package `my-react-components`. However, when I install this component using:

`npm install my-react-components`

it has a LICENSE, package.json, and README.md. However there my index.js file is missing.

This is a package I am trying to install from an internal BitBucket repository. Here’s the relevant excerpts from package.json:

```
   "dependencies": {
       "react": "^16.11.0",
       "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
       "my-react-components": "latest"
       "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
    },

   "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "ssh://git@bitbucket.mycompany.com:7999/~myusername/my-react-components.git"
    },
```

In the React component I have tried various things so that it somehow exports the component:

```
export default Persons;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was a crazy problem! I hope this answer helps someone.

Turns out, that if one checks the npm registry, by coincidence there is a package with that exact name:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/my-react-components

In this case, `npm install` was installing from the npm registry, *not the internal BitBucket repository*. That’s why there was no `index.js` as the registry component has no such file.

Fixing the dependency to point to the BitBucket repository solved the problem. As an extra precaution, it’s worth renaming the component:

```
"dependencies": {
    “my-company-react-components": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.mycompany.com:7999/~myusername/my-company-react-components.git#master",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
```